# Los parámetros pueden crear objetos?

Tags: javascript, funciones, parametros

Me surgió una duda que no sé como comprobar, porque no me imprime nada en consola, pero tampoco me tira error. ¿Realmente con dos parámetros puedo crear un objeto?, es decir:

```js
function test(arg, arg2) {
  arg.arg2 = 10
}
```

Eso funcionaria como un objeto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando haces `arg.arg2 = 10`, no estas agregando el parametro `arg2` al objecto `arg`. Sino agregando una nueva propiedad con el nombre de `arg2` a la referencia del objecto que le enviaste como primer parametro.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function fn(arg1, arg2){

  // agregamos la propiedad arg2 al objecto que es enviado en el primer parametro arg1
  arg1.numero = 10;
}

// objecto vacio
var obj = {};
// enviamos el objeto al metodo
fn(obj, null);

// como se agrego una nueva propiedad a la referencia del objecto
// podemos acceder a ella fuera de la ejecucion del mismo.
console.log(obj);
```

Notaras como a pesar de que se declaro un objeto vacio, cuando se ejecuta el metodo, este objeto ahora tiene la propiedad `numero`. Recuerda que esto no esta relacionado al nombre del argumento.

Answer (score 1):

depende de como lo implementes

https://www.dofactory.com/tutorial/javascript-function-objects

```
function Book (type, author) {
    this.type = type;
    this.author = author;
    this.getDetails = function () {
        return this.type + " written by " + this.author;
    }
}
var book = new Book("Fiction", "Peter King");
alert(book.getDetails());        // => Fiction written by Peter King
```

Puedes hacer uso de los Prototype a partir de una función tengo entendido

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp

```
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eye;
}

Person.prototype.name = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
};
```